# Styling responsive layout in amp-img

Tags: html, css, responsive-images, google-amp, amp-img

Since I've implemented Google AMP I am struggling with this problem. Every time I add an image with a `width` far smaller than my website `width`, `amp-img` automatically add margins to keep the aspect ratio, like this:

[image]

I have tried other layouts mentioned in the [official documentation],(https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout#supported-values-for-the-layout-attribute) like `flex-item`.

With `flex-item` for example, I can get the desired behavior in the desktop version, that is, reducing the total margin of the image to look like this:

[image]

But in the mobile version, when an image is wider that the screen, the image overflows left and right.

Is there a way I can tweek the `responsive layout` in order to remove such larger margins when the image is relative small?

Investigating a bit in the code, the problem seems to be caused by the element `i-amphtml-sizer`, which is an element google-amp adds automatically and of which I have no control of.

[image]

> I am not posting the url for my blog post in case it is considered spam, but if for some reason you need it, I'll update the question.

## **UPDATE**

It [seems more people](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/7009) are having this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it! reading amp [documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-layout.md#sizes) on [github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml), in concrete the section on `amp-html-layout`, in "sizes" there is an example saying:

> In the following example, if the viewport is wider than 320px, the image will be 320px wide, otherwise, it will be 100vw wide (100% of the viewport width).

```
<amp-img src="https://acme.org/image1.png"
    width="400" height="300"
    layout="responsive"
    sizes="(min-width: 320px) 320px, 100vw">
</amp-img>
```

Previously, my image was:

```
<figure>
  <amp-img 
     on="tap:lightbox1" 
     role="button" 
     tabindex="0" 
     layout="responsive" src="/img/securitynow.jpg"
     width="100"
     height="100">
  </amp-img>
</figure>
```

After reading AMP documentation:

```
<figure>
  <amp-img
     sizes="(min-width: 100px) 100px, 100vw" 
     on="tap:lightbox1" 
     role="button" 
     tabindex="0" 
     layout="responsive" src="/img/securitynow.jpg"
     width="100"
     height="100">
  </amp-img>
</figure>
```

Now it is displaying well on all screen sizes:

[image]

In order to work with all kind of image sizes, I'm following this rule:

```
 sizes="(min-width: withOfImage) WithOfImage, 100vw"
```

This way, when the screen is wider than the image width, the image will have its original width, otherwise the image will be `100%` of the viewport width.